# How to add button and text in the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have to add the text "Map1" and the button "NaviMe" into the navigation bar, which is there(on the screen), but I do not know why is it not editable. Would you please help me ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your Navigation Bar outside the View scope. It should look like here: [image: navigation item outside view scope]

Answer (score 0):

In StoryBoard You just drag out a Bar Button Item and drop it on the right end of the view controller's navigation bar:
[image]